# If the same image is being referred multiple times within a HTML page, does the image data get transferred once or multiple times?

Tags: html, image

Say I have two `<img>` in a HTML page and both refer to the same image link. Is the image data transferred once (ie. cached) or two times?

Comment: @Oded is correct.  A browser will cache an images address.  Also of note, you can use the same image on different domains to benefit from caching.  This is referred to as Content Delivery Networks (CDN).  If you use an image URL such as "www.example.com/images/a.jpg" on site A and then visit site B which shows the exact same image from www.example.com, your browser should pull the cache for this image that was first loaded from site A.  This goes for non-images.  Google stores JS frameworks for this reason. http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Comment: @Fozzyuw thx for the extra tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image will be transferred one time only and cached in the local browser cache.

You can test this by using a web proxy or looking at the `net` tab of the browser dev tools.